# Is it possible to still perform click-jacking with if a website has SSL?

Tags: tls, websites, clickjacking

There are someways to stop click-jacking on websites without HTTPS, but I have seen that you cannot perform click-jacking on website the does have SSL. Is this true or can you still perform click-jacking?

Comment: What exactly makes you think that click-jacking on HTTPS is not possible, i.e. which part of click-jacking depends on having HTTP instead of HTTPS? In my opinion no part depends on it and click-jacking is still possible with HTTPS.

Comment: It not really perform-able on any site; way too many  screen size combos these days. the days of 1024x768 IE6 being half the useragents are long over...

Comment: @dandavis I don't think static 'screen size' is relevant ...

Comment: @schroeder: Eve has to know where to place the invisible "transfer funds" button to get Alice to unwittingly click on it. we're talking about clickjacking, not just hidden links; it usually requires a GET payload injection and/or CSRF as well to queue up the important human-approved form button...

Comment: @dandavis I think you're a little behind on the state of the art: https://medium.com/@Matt_S/clickjacking-facebook-likes-step-by-step-bc0846d55e56

Comment: @schroeder: that works because the whole page is a button and facebook users lazily stay logged in 24/7. Liking must not be important/risky enough to demand a confirmation, and facebook wants all those home-phoning hidden pages running everywhere, so it doesn't behoove them to prevent it. worth consideration though, touche. i still think that doing anything major requires a targeted attack.

Answer (score 2):

You should read about what [SSL (HTTPS) really is](https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/what-is-ssl/). SSL has no connection to click-jacking, and it is still possible regardless. As dandavis stated in comments, proffesional pages nowadays are custom-scaled to browser resolution, so Click-Jacking is really not often used tactic. Modern websites also use [headers to prevent click-jacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet) by telling browser not to load them in `<frame>` or `<iframe>` from other sites.